# why is STS not able use more than groovy compilers at a time?

Tags: groovy, spring-tool-suite

I have d/t projects which use d/t *groovy compiler version* but as I am using **STS** , it seems like it is not possible.

Any reason why? Or any experience for solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Due to Groovy-Eclipse's **tight integration with the compiler**, only one version of the compiler can be used in the workspace at one time.
Also *switching compiler levels requires a restart*.   [detail](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Switching+within+Groovy-Eclipse)